# Send custom parameters to FacebookRequest

Tags: php, facebook, session, facebook-php-sdk, php-5.5

This is my code:

```
$message = $_POST['content'];
echo $message;
exit();

if ($session) {
try {
    // $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
    // $response = $request->execute();
    // $me = $response->getGraphObject();
    // echo $me->getProperty('email');

    $postRequest = new FacebookRequest($session, 'POST', '/me/feed', $message);
    $postResponse = $postRequest->execute()->getGraphObject();

    // uploading image to user timeline using facebook php sdk v4
    //$response = (new FacebookRequest(
    //    $session, 'POST', '/me/photos', array(
    //        'source' => new CURLFile('picture.jpg', 'image/jpg'),
    //       'message' => 'User provided message'
    //        )
    //    )
    //)->execute()->getGraphObject();
    //if($response) {
    //    echo "Done";
    //}
} catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

At this point I am able to print the content of $message anywhere in my code, except inside the **try block** I came to the conclusion that is has something to do with the Facebook session. When the session is establish and the **try block** gets executed, for some reason the value of $_POST['content']; disappears and I get the error:

Undefined index: content in /var/www/html/submit.php

I know that **$session** its getting the session information from **getSessionFromRedirect** and I'm pretty sure when this redirect happens, the $_POST['content'] doesn't get carried over that session.

My question is: How can I add information that comes from a form element (textarea), assign it to a variable and pass that value to **$postRequest = new FacebookRequest($session, 'POST', '/me/feed', $message);** in order for my app to display such custom message?

Thanks!

This is the index.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Facebook API Post</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
</head>
<body>  
<form action="submit.php" method="POST">
    <h2>Post to Facebook!</h2>

    <label for="postcontent">Post: </label>
    <textarea name="content" id="postcontent" placeholder="Enter your post here..." rows="5"></textarea>

    <button type="submit">Post To Wall!</button>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The exit() function is there for debug purposes.

Comment: What does your index file look like.

Comment: @phwd Do you have an idea on how to accomplish this? Thanks!